# Get an object to remove itself from a list in another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a "connection pool handler" which in its class has a array list of "Connection Handlers" I was wondering whether it is possible to have the "Connection Handlers" remove themselves from said list when they close the connections themselves and if so how?

```
public class ConnectionHandlerPool
{
private static final ArrayList<ConnectionThread> POOL = new ArrayList<ConnectionThread>;

<code to get stuff out of pool>
```

Connection thread class

```
public class ConnectionHandlerThread
{
<stuff that creates the connection>
<stuff that if exceptions occur i.e. a stream or socket closes it needs to close all the connections and remove from pool>
<that way of removing it from arraylist in the class above it>
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] to illustrate what you are trying to do. Showing actual code will help us understand what you are trying to describe in English.

Comment: You wrote your own connection pool handler?

Comment: The Connection Handlers have no knowledge that they are being stored in a list. To remove them from the list, they have to call a method on the Handler to do it for them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have done now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this doesn't require complicated listener design or even interfaces. Note: Following code does not take into account all other required logic (checking out, ensuring a connection can't be checked out twice, etc.).

```
public class ConnectionHandlerPool {
    private static final List<ConnectionThread> pool = new ArrayList<ConnectionThread>();
    // When new threads are created, they get a reference to the pool they're in
    private void addConnection() {
        pool.add(new ConnectionThread(pool));
    }
    private void disconnect(ConnectionThread ct) {
        pool.remove(ct);
    }
}

public class ConnectionHandlerThread {
    private final ConnectionHandlerPool pool;
    public ConnectionHandlerThread(ConnectionHandlerPool pool) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    private void destroy() {
        pool.disconnect(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering and talking to some technical mates I have resolved it.

1. Create a interface which has a method in it that takes a ConnectionHandlerThread
2. Have the pool implement said interface and have said method remove the ConnectionHandlerThread removed from the arraylist.
3. Have the connection handler pool class add itself as a listener to the ConnectionHandlerThread by creating a method called addListener
4. Call addListener in the thread and have it pull through the interface
5. Call the interface.method from the class when you want to remove it.

Comment: Well that's one overly complicated way of doing it. The interface and listener functionality is unnecessary, since you could've basically done `handlerPool.removeConnection(this)`, provided that connections have a reference to a (single) pool.

Comment: @kayman the issue is java passes by value so I cant provide them with a reference to a single pool as when i go to `runhandlerPool.removeConnection(this)` it will only edit the version that is within itself and none of the others.

Comment: No. Java passes everything by value yes, including references. It will work perfectly as I described, but you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value